# jquery widget tab refresh div to when update table finish

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a jquery tab that display divs that have table with edit function that uses a lytebox to popup my update form.

Problem is I need to refresh the page to update the content and I'm kinda lost on the url and the process of the update thing. I am used to a single page update ever since. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php  
    session_start();  

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {  
        header("Location: login.php");  
        exit;  
    }else if($_SESSION['role']!=='ADMIN'){
         header("Location: login.php");  
        exit; 
    }
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/sample.js"></script>
<script src="./js/quicksearch.js"></script>
<script src="./js/lytebox.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/sample.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/table_blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/lytebox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").hide();
    $("#datepicker2").hide();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
    });
    $("#category").on('change', function () {
        if ($("#category").val() == 'ORIGINAL_DEADLINE') {
            $("#datepicker").show();
            $("#datepicker2").show();
            $("#datepicker2").show();

        } else {
            $("#datepicker").hide();
            $("#datepicker2").hide();
        }
    }); 

});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Overdue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Next 60 days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Others</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">No Deadline</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Finished Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="./manage_users.php">Manage Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="./report.php">Generate Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form method="post" action="table.php" >
    Category<select name="category" id="category">
        <option value='APP_NUMBER' >APP_NUMBER</option>
        <option value='SPOC_ASSIGNED' >SPOC_ASSIGNED</option>
        <option value='BORROWER_NAME' >BORROWER_NAME</option>
        <option value='DEFERRED_TYPE' >DEFERRED_TYPE</option>
        <option value='ORIGINAL_DEADLINE' >ORIGINAL_DEADLINE</option>
        </select>
    Search Text<input type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Type to Search" />
     <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1" placeholder="Input Start Date"> 
     <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2" placeholder="Input End Date">  
    <input type="submit" name="cmdsearch" id="cmdsearch" value="Search"/>
    </form>


    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
     <?php
        //conection: 
    include "conn.php";
     //consultation: 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ORIGINAL_DEADLINE)>1 and SUBMITTED_PENDING='PENDING'"; 
     //execute the query. 
     if($result = $link->query($query)){
           echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT  </td>".
                "<td> EDIT  </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";

          }
          $result->close();
          echo "</table>\r\n";
        } else {
          printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
         ?>
        </div>


        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <?php

            // Perform next SQL Query
            if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ORIGINAL_DEADLINE)<60 and SUBMITTED_PENDING='PENDING'")){
                echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";
                 }
                 echo "</table>\r\n";
                 $result->close();
            }  else {
                 printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
            }
            ?>

        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <?php

            // Perform next SQL Query
             if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where ORIGINAL_DEADLINE < current_date and SUBMITTED_PENDING='PENDING'")){
                echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";
                 }
                 echo "</table>\r\n";
                 $result->close();
            }  else {
                 printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
            }
            ?>

        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <?php

            if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where ORIGINAL_DEADLINE='' and SUBMITTED_PENDING='PENDING'")){
                echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";
                 }          
                 echo "</table>\r\n";
                 $result->close();
            }  else {
                 printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
            }

            ?>

        </div>

        <div id="tab5" class="tab">
            <?php

            if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where SUBMITTED_PENDING='SUBMITTED'")){
                echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td>EDIT</td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";
                 }          
                 echo "</table>\r\n";
                 $result->close();
            }  else {
                 printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
            }

            ?>

        </div>

        <div id="tab_search">  
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['cmdsearch'])){
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $text=$_POST['txtsearch'];
        $date1=$_POST['date1'];
        $date2=$_POST['date2'];



//connect to db

     $link = mysqli_connect("xxxxxx","xxxxx","qwerty123","xxxxx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
     if($link->connect_error){
          printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
          exit();
     }

    if($category==='ORIGINAL_DEADLINE'){
         $sql="SELECT * FROM COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where ($category BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')";

    }else{
            $sql="SELECT * FROM COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where $category LIKE '%$text%'";

    }

    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);

            }

        $result = $link->query($sql);
         echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".

                 "</tr>";
    }
    }
        ?>
        </div>




</div>

<?php
$link->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my updated script when the user click my table:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("10.20.8.70","stcutie","qwerty123","export_workflow") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
    session_start();  

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {  
        header("Location: login.php");  
        exit;  
    } 


$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$role=$_SESSION['role'];
$id=$_GET['id'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//filter database for update
$query = "SELECT * from COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where ID='$id'; " or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

//execute the query. 
$result = $link->query($query); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$app_uid=$row['APP_NUMBER'];
$spoc_remarks=$row['SPOC_REMARKS']; 
$file_location=$row['FILED_LOCATION'];
$juw_remarks=$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS'];
$cosu_remarks=$row['COSU_REMARKS'];
$smu_notes=$row['SMU_NOTES'];
$pending_complete=$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING'];

?>
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/form_style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="form-style-10" id="dynamicField">
<h1>Edit Form</h1>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php $id;?>" >
<p id="spoke_remarks">Spoc Remarks<input type="text" name="spoke_remarks" value="<?php echo $spoc_remarks; ?>"></p>
<br>
<p id="file_location"> File Location<input type="text" name="file_location" value="<?php echo $file_location;?>" > </p>
<br>
<p id="smu_notes">SMU NOTES<input type="text" name="smu_notes" value="<?php echo $smu_notes;?>" ></p>
<br>
<p id="pending_complete">Pending/SUBMITTED<select name="pending_complete" >
        <option value='' >--SELECT--</option>
        <option value='PENDING' >PENDING</option>
        <option value='SUBMITTED' >SUBMITTED</option>
        </select> </p>
<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="update" id="update"/>
</div>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    if($role=='SPOC'){
    $spoc_remarks2=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['spoke_remarks']);

    $sql="UPDATE COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT set SPOC_REMARKS = '$spoc_remarks2' WHERE ID='$id'";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

           } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);

            }

    $sql2="INSERT INTO collateral_management.CHANGE_LOG (DATE, USERS_LOGGED, DESCRIPTION, OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE, APP_ID,IP_ADDRESS)
            VALUES 
            (now(),'$username','Spoc $username edit remarks','$spoc_remarks','$spoc_remarks2','$app_uid','$ip');";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need jQuery, except for the opening the popup and feeding the form from the table ? You want the table to be dynamically updated, or you don't mind if there is a page reload ?

Comment: i want my table to be dynamically updated. In my other exercises on programming I used a window.open('index.php','_parent') but jquery tabs is a little tricky cause it uses divs

Comment: Dude, you shouldn't post your ip, user and password. If they are real, everybody can mess up your db right now. Change it ASAP, and if you're using something simillar anywhere, change it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve it so, I made the tabs like a menu bar and just put a js window.load for refresh ^_^